# Topology: interior points and boundary points

Tags: general-topology

> For each of the following sets determine whether it is open or closed, and then find its interior, limit and boundary points.

The questions and my answers are as follows. I have been given no answers for these questions – are mine correct?

1. $\Bbb Z×\{0\}=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\Bbb R^2:x_1\in\Bbb Z,x_2=0\}$ – not open, closed, no interior points, no limit points, no boundary points
2. $\{x\in\Bbb R^2:x_1=\frac1n,n\in\Bbb N,x_2=0\}$ – not open, not closed, no interior points, limit point of $(0,0)$, boundary point of $(0,0)$
3. $\{x\in\Bbb R^2: 1\le x_1\le2\}$ – not open, closed, interior points of $1<x_1<2$, all points are limit points, boundary points are $x_1=1$ or $x_1=2$
4. $\{x\in\Bbb R^2:1<x_1<2\}$ – open, not closed, all points are interior, all points are limits, no boundary points
5. $\{x\in\Bbb R^2:1\le\Vert x\Vert_2\le 2\}$ – not open, closed, interior points of $1<\Vert x\Vert_2<2$, all points limits, boundary points $\Vert x\Vert_2=1$ or $\Vert x\Vert_2=2$

Answer (score 1):

1. Not open-correct. Closed-correct. No interior points-correct. No limit points correct

No boundary points - incorrect- how can a set have no boundary *and* no interior?

---

2. Looks OK, but you also have to be able to prove all those things.

---

3. Looks OK, but you also have to be able to prove all those things.

---

4. Open, not closed, all points interior - correct. All points are limits - *incomplete*. Limit points of a set need not be elements of that set. They can (and in this case are) be other limit points. Same goes for boundary points. The set has a boundary, even if the boundary is not part of it.

---

5. Looks OK, but you also have to be able to prove all those things.

Comment: @5xum....In (1),  your sequence $<1-1/n>$ does not have all elements in $\mathbb Z$.